# Need help identifying a mystery component with double-diode marking

Tags: power-supply, diodes, identification, rectifier, schottky

I've found this MOSFET-shaped component inside a Dell laptop power supply (I've lost the case so I can't tell you any details, sorry):

[image: Photo]

The problem is that I can't find any datasheet for it anywhere.

I will try and describe it in terms of the lines of text on the front:

- Line 1: **C6312**
- Line 2: ***A picture of two diodes facing each other***.
- Line 3: **004**

For the most part, it looks exactly like a MOSFET, metal back etc, and it is also mounted on a heat sink if that is useful.

Through some research I think I've narrowed it down to a **Schottky barrier rectifier stack** based on the symbol of the two diodes facing each other.

This isn't super serious or urgent, but I'm really interested to know what it is!

Comment: A photo would help.  If not, then specify the actual package (e.g. TO220) because MOSFETs come in quite a few different packages.

Comment: I just added a photo which should help.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be part of the original design, but a hack or a bodge added as an afterthought. Are you sure the power supply had not been serviced/hacked before?

Comment: I'm 100% sure it's never been opened before. I got it off my dad who was throwing it away and he's a super safety freak. He was the only owner and would never open it, let along modify it. On the other half of the PCB, it was also heatshrinked along with a few other wires, so it had to have been part of the original design. Plus it has designated holes to solder the wires to.

Comment: Probably it is more likely some form of dual common-cathode rectifier diode (similar to [this](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/345/sr1620c-sr16200c-355478.pdf)).

Comment: The answers have done a good job of identifying this one, but it's important to be aware that lots of different components can come in a TO-220 package, not just MOSFETs.  Some common ones would be BJTs, IGBTs, SCRs, diodes, resistors, voltage regulators, etc.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are on the right track, but the 12 in the part number is a red herring, IMO. Probably a date-code.

After a bit of detective work, the most likely candidate I found was this [ESAC63-004 common cathode Schottky diode array](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=308112&part-number=ESAC63-004):

> [image]

From what you say, it could be the rectifier of the output of the power supply, as can be seen in an image of a DELL power supply found [here](https://www.google.it/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj61c-TjMDVAhVFbFAKHUcyBwgQjBwIBA&url=http%3A%2F%2F320volt.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F01%2Fschema-circuit-dell-pa12-19v-notebook-adapter-smps-1d07012-3-34a.png&psig=AFQjCNErHOxbR1G8hFYdLoktNx_pZ9CViQ&ust=1502021723011428) (emphasis on the image is mine):

[image]

---

## **EDIT**

[Another datasheet for the same part](http://www.dialelectrolux.ru/files/file/fuji/schottky/esac63-004r.pdf) can be definitive (yellow highlighting is mine):

> [image]

[...]

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a Silicon Diode, you might want to check this datasheet

http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/218943/FUJI/ESAC63-004R.html